# Using an integer as an SQL Alchemy selectable

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to generate sqlalchemy code to match this SQL statement:

```
SELECT table.id, table.value, 1 as new_column FROM table;
```

I can get `select([table.c.id, table.c.value, 1])` to work no problem, and it adds a new column to the results with the value of 1 as expected, but I have no control over the name of the column.  I've tried to figure out a way to use label, but since the integer is not a sqlalchemy column, I can't use it.

Is there a way to get this the same behavior as the about raw sql in sqlalchemy?

In the worst case I can just use raw sql, but I would much prefer to use the sqlalchemy table object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select([table.c.id, table.c.value, literal("1").label("new_column")])
```